# Which commit to use when git commit?

Tags: git

For example, in the beginning, `master` is in `commit01`, which is OK, then I merged `branch001` which contains 2 commits into `master`, then became:

```
commit04 Merge branch001 into master
commit03 commit from branch001
commit02 commit from branch001
commit01 master commit
```

Then I found that there is a big bug in `branch001`, so I want to go back to `commit01`, if I use `git revert`, which commit should I use?

Comment: Revert the merge commit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you didn't pushed your master then reset *local/master* with *origin/master*

```
$ git fetch
$ git reset --hard origin/master
```

If already push then *revert* your merge commit (commit message like `Merge branch 'branch-name' of ...`)

```
$ git log                  # copy the merge-commit-hash
$ git revert <commit-hash> # revert merge commit

$ git push origin HEAD     # push to origin master
```

Answer (score 0):

if you git revert commit04, it will revert all of the changes to the master branch performed by the merge.

If you haven't pushed this to a remote yet you can run git reset --hard commit01 to restore your working tree to its state at commit01 and erase commits02-4.

Comment: If commit04 is not a merge commit but a normal commit, does that means I have to revert `commit04` and `commit03` and `commit02` separately?